# C# Excel Add In -- Programatically Add In Memory Drop Down/Pick List

Tags: c#, excel, vsto

I have been experimenting with creating an Excel add in in C#.  I was wondering if it is possible to programatically create a drop down list for a column where the items do not have to be in the worksheet?  That is, I know it can be done using a data validation and a range of cells but I do not want the list of drop down items to be visible to the user/to be editable.

Any insight/links to aid in this would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You could use data validation, setting up the list in code, using something along these lines:

```
var worksheet = (Worksheet)Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.ActiveSheet;
     var cell = (Range)worksheet.Cells[1, 1];
     cell.Validation.Add(
        XlDVType.xlValidateList, 
        XlDVAlertStyle.xlValidAlertStop, 
        XlFormatConditionOperator.xlBetween,
        "A, B, C, D, E");
```

This will create a data validation list with items A, B, C etc... These are still editable by the user through the validation menu, though.

Comment: Thank you for your response.  I tried this approach by creating a string with all my items on the fly.  It works for a small number of items but throws an exception for a large number of items.  Is there any way to work around this?

Comment: How many items are we talking about? If you have a large number of items, a drop-down might not be the best approach anyways, because it becomes unpractical to use.

Comment: Most will be in the hundreds but some will be in the thousands (perhaps tens of thousands in extreme cases but never hundreds of thousands).  The standard usage would be typing in with autocomplete based on items in the drop down.  I would like to mimic how the drop downs work in the TFS Excel add in (if you happen to be familiar with it).